# Cannot set error-handler to throw ErrorException in PHP-8

Tags: php, macos, docker, terminal, php-8

My script has the following code:

```
set_error_handler(function(int $severity, string $message, string $filename, int $lineNumber) : void {
    throw new ErrorException($message, 0, $severity, $filename, $lineNumber);
});

function test() : string {
    return $test;
}

test();
```

Running the script on PHP 7.3.11 (on macOS 10.15.7) works as expected and shows the following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Undefined variable: test in
> .../index.php:9 Stack trace:
>
> #0 .../index.php(9): {closure}(8, 'Undefined varia...', '...', 9, Array)
>
> #1 .../index.php(12): test()
>
> #2 {main}
>
> Next TypeError: Return value of test() must be of the type string,
> null returned in .../index.php:9
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 .../index.php(12): test()
>
> #1 {main}   thrown in .../index.php on line 9

But on PHP-8 (`php:8.0.0rc1-apache` docker image), it gets stuck on a loop and nothing is displayed.

Removing the `set_error_handler` works though

> Warning: Undefined variable $test in .../index.php on line 9
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: test(): Return value must be of type string, null returned in .../index.php:9
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 .../index.php(12): test()
>
> #1 {main}
> thrown in .../index.php on line 9

Is this a bug, or did something change in the new version? I tried it on PHP CLI btw.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: have you checked whether you are using the same level of error reporting?

Comment: @NicoHaase Won't matter as the  script never stops executing in php-8 in the first place

Comment: This is indeed a bug, fixed in https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/1748b8111e97f14f709553c7a5498fcdfcd6c754.

Comment: @NikiC Thanks, so this fix should be available in the next rc, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it was indeed a bug and has been resolved in the 2nd release candidate (PHP-8.0.0 RC2).